# How are the keys CIDetectorMinFeatureSize and CIDetectorAspectRatio used for CIDetector?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-image, quartz-core

How is `CIDetectorMinFeatureSize` supposed to be used when setting up a CIDetector for either face or rectangle recognition? The [description at Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIDetector_Ref/index.html) does not tell me anything:

> A key used to specify the minimum size that the detector will
>   recognize as a feature.
>
> The value for this key is an NSNumber object ranging from 0.0 through
>   1.0 that represents a fraction of the minor dimension of the image.

The documentation says it ranges from 0.0 to 1.0 and then I look at the WWDC slides of session 514 and they set the value to "100"...?

It is as much a secret to me as the (undocumented?) `CIDetectorAspectRatio`.

Let's say I'm trying to detect an A4 paper sheet which is 30cm x 21cm and has an aspect ratio of 1.4 - what would I set for the two keys?

Comment: Instead of voting down, would you please explain how this question can be improved or give another explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CIDetectorAspectRatio is used by CIRectangleDetector to constrain the search.  In your example, the value of the CIDetectorAspectRatio key should be @(1.43).

The CIDetectorMinFeatureSize is also used to constrain the search. Only a rectangles greater than the specified fraction of the input image size will be returned

Comment: Reference to documentation?

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation you can find about "CIDetectorAspectRatio" :

An option specifying the aspect ratio (width divided by height) of rectangles to search for.

The value of this key is an NSNumber object whose value is a positive floating-point number. Use this option with the CIDetectorTypeRectangle detector type to fine-tune the accuracy of the detector. For example, to more accurately find a business card (3.5 x 2 inches) in an image, specify an aspect ratio of 1.75 (3.5 / 2).

Available in iOS 8.0 and later.

[enter link description here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIDetector_Ref/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Feature_Detection_Keys)